# Como fazer APPEND em um componente criado automaticamente, não esta encontrando o ID do elemento

Tags: html, jquery, aplicação-web

Estou tentando adicionar uma div via append pois estou adicionando em uma tabela que tem componestes criados automático como filtro, responsiva, paginação, assim sendo gostaria de colocar dentro duma dessas div que fica ao lado do filtro porem ao colocar o id da div desses componentes via jquery ele não consegue identificar e não adiciona

por exemplo:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      addSwitches  = '<div class="switch"><label>Off<input type="checkbox" 
      <span class="lever"></span>On</label></div>'
      $("#data-table-simple_wrapper").append(addSwitches);
</script>
```

ou

```
$("#data-table-simple_wrapper").append("<p>teste</p>");
```

a div "data-table-simple_wrapper" não tem no html porem quando inspeciono a tabela consigo pegar o id da div e adicionar manualmete editando o html para testar porem o jquery não encontra esse ID

Comment: Não tem no HTML pois essa div é gerada por algum plugin?

Seria interessante postar o trecho de HTML do inspecionar se for o caso. E Seu código javascript está no mesmo arquivo do HTML? Em que posição exatamente, início ou fim?

Answer (score 0):

Adicione `$( document ).ready(function()` em seu código, pois no momento da execução do javascript o documento html pode não ter sido ainda totalmente carregado, veja documentação https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $( document ).ready(function() {
            addSwitches  = '<div class="switch"><label>Off<input type="checkbox" 
            <span class="lever"></span>On</label></div>'
            $("#data-table-simple_wrapper").append(addSwitches);
      });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Para afetar elementos no html que não existiam no DOM inicialmente (criados dinamicamente) você pode usar o document antes e depois o find pela div. Com isso ele vai procurar dentro do documento **atual** e irá achar sua div.

```
$(document).find("#data-table-simple_wrapper").append("<p>teste</p>");
```